# Magento 2.3: How to print order without invoice

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, sales-order, pdf, print

It looks like in the admin, you're only able to print the order via the invoice or shipment -- but orders that are pending that were paid via PO or COD methods, there's no option to print the order.

Is it possible to print order directly from the admin order view regardless of invoice / shipping status?

I don't have any code to share yet as I'm not quite sure where to start and haven't really found much info anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento does not have any default feature to print an Order. You could try installing extension. I have used one of the extension for my client, it gives you ability to print single order as well as bulk orders in a Pdf and most important its free ;-)

Try installing https://store.fooman.co.nz/magento-extension-print-order-pdf-m2.html .

Hope it finds you helpful.

Comment: Thank you, actually came across this extension shortly after posting my question and is exactly what we were looking for

Comment: Thank you, it working fine, but i need to change the column name in the grid.How can i achieve this?. For example: i need to change the column name **SKU** to **HSN**.